# QGIS loads without its python module, postgreSQL, and plPython3u

Tags: qgis, python, postgresql

In the (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6) the "installation-notes.htm" for postgreSQL 9.6 show python 3.3 as being the compatible version.  I installed it, put it into my windows 7 path/variables, and can run python 3.3 at the command line.  After issuing a `CREATE LANGUAGE plpython3u`, I was able to write plpython3u functions.  But, QGIS uses python 2.7.5.  When I load QGIS, it will no longer load its python console because it explains that python33.dll is not compatible.  I suppose I could try reverting to python 2.7, in windows 7, but is that supposed to be compatible with postgreSQL 9.6?

Combining the advice of the two responses, I edited my environmental variables to remove any mention of python3.3.  QGis loads, and with the python console! I am not sure whether the python 3.3 environmental variables may be needed in order for plpython3u functions to work in postgreSQL.

Comment: Maybe related: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpython-python23.html. According to http://blog.qgis.org/2016/01/17/help-us-to-plan-for-qgis-3-0/ the next QGIS version will support python 3 too (and only). For the current QGIS version, it might help **not** to put Python 3 in the Windows path/variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the EDB PostgreSQL 9.6 offers a library for python2. The BigSQL for windows on other hand only offers plpython2.

Anyway I think you can get QGIS to use it's own try this:

run the OSGeo4W.bat file that is in the Program Files\QGIS folder

Then at the prompt type:

QGIS

That should lauch qgis with it's own settings.

If it doesn't you might need to create a custom batch or edit that one to override PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH.